# XSLT - select processing instruction nodes that has a value

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I need to select processing instruction that has a value.

example:

```
<doc>
    <?aaa?>
    <?aaa bbb?>
</doc>
```

above example, I can select both pi using `//processing-instruction('aaa')` xpath. any idea how can I select pi that has a value. (this example, only  should be selected)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `//processing-instruction('aaa')[normalize-space()]`.